# django docker-compose deleting data from mongo database when i am doing "docker-compose down" and again"up"

Tags: python, django, docker

DockerFile:

```
    FROM python:3.6

    WORKDIR /usr/src/jobsterapi
    COPY ./ ./
    RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

    CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: "3"

    services:
      jobster_api:
        container_name: jobster
        build: ./
        # command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        command: "bash -c 'python src/manage.py makemigrations --no-input && python src/manage.py migrate --no-input && python src/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'"
        working_dir: /usr/src/jobster_api
        environment:
          REDIS_URI: redis://redis:6379
          MONGO_URI: mongodb://jobster:27017
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
          - ./:/usr/src/jobster_api
        links:
          - redis
          - elasticsearch
          - mongo


      #redis
      redis:
        image: redis
        environment:
          - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
        ports:
          - "6379:6379"

      elasticsearch:
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.0
        ports:
          - "9200:9200"
          - "9300:9300"

      mongo:
        image: mongo
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
```

I have done setup django with mongodb inside docker using following docker-compose
command. it is working fine every thing. but when i am adding any records
using "docker exec -it 'img id' /bin/bash" it is inserting data(i tried creating superuser for django
admin panel). but, when i am again making it "docker-compose up" after "docker-compose down" it is 
deleting all data from database showing empty records. so i am not able to access admin panel also for next timeself.

Please have a look.........

Answer (score 0):

Add a volumes to

```
mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - insert_mongos_stored_area
```

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: It is not common to use Mongo with Django. By default the database used by Django is SQLite.

Comment: i don't want sqlite .. i want mongo

Comment: Mongo is not going to work with Django, at least not out of the box.  I guess you could use https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine but that hasn't been updated in years.

Comment: This is the way to go, actually